# if a is a unit of $A$, it is also a unit of the quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $A$ is a nontrivial commutative ring with unity and $S$ is an ideal of $A$ s.t. $S\ne\{0_A\}$ and $S\ne A$ . Prove or find a counterexample: if $a\in A$ is a unit in $A$, then $a + S$ is a unit in $A/S$.

Any ideas on how I should prove this? I feel like this is not true but I'm not sure how to find a counter example.

Similarly, if $a$ is a zero divisor in $A$, would $a + S$ also be a zero divisor in $A/S$?

Comment: For the last question: consider $$A=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\\ S=3\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\\ a=2+6\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true since *ring* homomorphisms map units to units: for example, if

$$aa'=1\;\;\text{in}\;\;A\;,\;\;\text{then}\;\;(a+S)(a'+S)=1+S\;\;\text{in the quotient}\;\;A/S$$

and this last is the unit  in the quotient.

Comment: But how do we know that there exists a' + S?

Comment: @pl We know $\;a'\;$ exists as shown since $\;a\;$ is a unit in $\;A\;$ , and for **any element** in $\;A\;$ its image in the quotient exists!

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming all rings are unital and morphisms preserve the identity)

A unit is not contained in a proper ideal (convince yourself of this if you don't already know why). Hence for, for the setup you have outlined, $a^{-1} \not\in S$. Thus the inverse of $a + S$ in $A/S$ is $a^{-1} + S$ because $(a + S)(a^{-1} + S) = (aa^{-1} + S) = 1 + S$ which is the unit in $A/S$.